# openocd using linux [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=] error - hoverboard - AT32f403 chip

Tags: linux, st-link

I'm trying to reprogram my hoverboard which has the AT32f403 and using st link with openocd and ubuntu.
I started to do the steps presented in the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0KIMjl1BoU&t=252s

After the make install in the openocd
I got so many errors below,
anyone knows what to do to move foward?
[image]

Comment: It's broken, report it as a bug.  It may work if you remove the `-Werror` flag in the `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1):

The warnings means that on the switch statement, in case of a condition, the code may go to the next case because the break is missing.

Most likely you have something like:

```
switch (whatever)
    case '\n':
       if (!cmd_pos)
       {
           // do something
           break;
        }
        //<--- no break here
    case 'X':
}
```

This might be on purpose, or not. Not all compiler will catch this and perhaps you've got a newer compiler version that the code was tested with.

As Oskar pointed, you are compiling with the option to treat warning as error. You can disable that by removing the -Werror flag.

Comment: I just installed another vrsion of openocd and worked! thanks!

Comment: @BrunoPimenta if it helped you, you can mark the question as answered by validating the answer.